# Deployit integration with Gitlab

Tags: gitlab-ci, xl-deploy, deployit

I was using deployit (XLdeploy) with Jenkins and SVN as repo, but now I am planning to move to Gitlab. Is there any good documentation on how to integrate Gitlab with deployIT? I have searched but didn't get any reference documents.

Where should I start with this?

Is it the case that XLdeploy has come up with some integration with Gitlab?